# HTML Module: Set Default Workflow for Site option missing in 5.6

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I recently updated to DNN 5.6 and noticed that in my HTML module the option to set the workflow as the site default is missing.

Apparently this was removed in the lastest CE release of DNN ([forum here](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/tabid/795/forumid/199/postid/399722/scope/posts/default.aspx)).

Is this something I can set via SQL in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the UI was accidentally removed from the CE version as part of the re-organization of the HTML module in 5.6.0.

Here is the relevant code from HtmlTextController.UpdateWorkflow

```
Case "Site"
  PortalController.UpdatePortalSetting(ObjectID, "WorkflowID", WorkflowID.ToString)
  If ReplaceExistingSettings Then
    'Get All Tabs aon the Site
    For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, TabInfo) In tabController.GetTabsByPortal(ObjectID)
      tabController.DeleteTabSetting(kvp.Value.TabID, "WorkFlowID")
    Next
    'Get All Modules in the current Site
    For Each objModule As ModuleInfo In moduleController.GetModules(ObjectID)
      ClearModuleSettings(objModule)
    Next
  End If
```

Adding a WorkflowID portal setting is all that is needed to set the workflow for the whole portal, but it is important to ensure that all the tabs (pages) and HTML modules have their specific workflow settings cleared.

**Edit**

It turns out the controls are actually still there, but hidden by accident.  To make them visible again do the following.

- go to \DesktopModules\HTML
- open the file "Settings.ascx"
- Find  `<tr id="rowApplyTo" runat="server" visible="false">`
- change to `<tr id="rowApplyTo" runat="server" visible="true">`

Comment: The UI should be properly restored in the upcoming 5.6.1 release.

Comment: That was easy!  Thanks for your help.